# Characterization of bicycle graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

By "bicycle graph" I mean a minimal connected simple graph with at least two cycles.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoforest#Bicircular_matroid):

> There are three possible types of bicycle: a theta graph has two vertices that are connected by three internally disjoint paths, a figure 8 graph consists of two cycles sharing a single vertex, and a handcuff graph is formed by two disjoint cycles connected by a path.

The reference given is Streinu & Theran (2009), but I see there are multiple papers by those authors published in that year. So I would like to prove the statement myself.

I've determined that the minimal theta graph is obtained by adding an edge to $C_4$, the minimal handcuff graph is obtained by adding an edge to the disjoint union of two copies of $C_3$, and the minimal figure 8 graph is obtained by contracting the cut-edge in the minimal handcuff graph. Moreover, any graph of these three types is homeomorphic to the minimal graph of that type. It follows then that any theta, figure 8, or handcuff graph is a bicycle graph.

I am not sure how to prove the converse, however. This is just a personal curiosity of mine so hints would be preferred to a full solution.

Comment: How does a theta graph have exactly two cycles? I count three (the upper, the lower and the outer path on the symbol $\theta$).

Comment: @Arthur Good point. I have amended the definition to "at least two cycles."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the converse, I think the following should work.

Given a bicycle graph, consider the two shortest cycles.

Case 1:

> If they are vertex-disjoint, consider the shortest path connecting the cycles.  Any other edges would be extraneous, so you have a handcuff graph.

Case 2:

> If they share exactly one vertex, you have a figure 8 graph.

Case 3:

> If they share two vertices, you have two vertices with at least three paths between them, giving a theta graph.  The shortest cycle assumption helps prevent messy intersections of these paths.

Comment: Yes, this is correct (and quite elegant). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks, I'm happy to be of help!